# javascript defineProperty to make an attribute non enumerable

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, ecmascript-5, defineproperty

I'm trying to use defineProperty to made attributes not appear in for...in cycle, but it doesn't work. Is this code correct?

```
function Item() {
    this.enumerable = "enum";
    this.nonEnum = "noEnum";
}
Object.defineProperty(Item, "nonEnum", { enumerable: false });

var test = new Item();

for (var tmp in test){
    console.log(tmp);
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`Item` does not have a property named `nonEnum` ([check it out](http://jsfiddle.net/WMTbQ/1/)). It is a (constructor) function that will create an object that has a property called `nonEnum`.

So this one would work:

```
var test = new Item();
Object.defineProperty(test, "nonEnum", { enumerable: false });
```

You could also write this function like this:

```
function Item() {
    this.enumerable = "enum";
    Object.defineProperty(this, "nonEnum", { 
        enumerable: false, 
        value: 'noEnum' 
    });
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WMTbQ/2/)