# json back reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-structures, tree

I've a hierarchical json object, I want to traverse it and attach a parent node to each element. This is what I've done

```
function attach_back_reference(hierarchy, parent){
    hierarchy.parent = parent;
    for(var i in hierarchy){
        if(jQuery.isPlainObject(hierarchy[i]))
            attach_back_reference(hierarchy[i], hierarchy);
    }
}
```

But this is giving error. `Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do

```
for(var i in hierarchy){
```

after adding the `parent` property, one value of `i` will be `"parent"`, so you end up setting the child as its own grandparent infinitely.

You can see this in

```
var o = {};
o.x = o;
for (var i in o) { alert(i); }
```

which alerts `"x"`.

Move the loop to the top.

```
function attach_back_reference(hierarchy, parent){
    for(var i in hierarchy){
        if(jQuery.isPlainObject(hierarchy[i]))
            attach_back_reference(hierarchy[i], hierarchy);
    }
    hierarchy.parent = parent;
}
```

Alternatively, if you only need this to work on newer interpreters, you can try making the parent property unenumerable : [javascript defineProperty to make an attribute non enumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10269652/javascript-defineproperty-to-make-an-attribute-non-enumerable)

Comment: Thanks. I overlooked that. also I found that It doesn't work if I've an array in the middle of hierarchy

Comment: also can you tell me how to handle arrays ? so that it assigns parent to first object(non-array) ancestor ?

Answer (score 0):

You have an infinite loop there.

You are setting the parent of each object as itself.

Comment: But I am passing `attach_back_reference(hierarchy[i], hierarchy)` so `hierarchy[i].parent = hierarchy` will be executed